# What is a PL mapping?

Tags: functions

In a proof of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem I've encuntered the notion of a PL mapping between two n-spheres. Does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PL stands for "piecewise linear".  Roughly, it means a map which can be decomposed as a piecewise linear map with respect to suitable triangulations of source andtarget.  For a more precise description, see the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_manifold), or [these lecture notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/937.html) of Jacob Lurie.  (Note that is probably implicit in the discussion you are reading that the $n$-spheres are given their standard PL structures.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

A PL mapping is a piecewise linear map.